# sending actions from within a component in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out how to handle in a single place a "login" action, that must be activated from a button click and "enter" keypress;

in my template I've wrapped everything inside a "login-functions" component

```
//template home.hbs
{{#login-functions}}     
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">

    <div id="login" {{action "login"}}>     
{{/login-functions}}


//component components/login-functions.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        login: function() {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var self = this;

            Utils.login(email, password).done(function(res) {
                localStorage.setItem('Access-Token', res.data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.user_id);
                self.transitionToRoute('feed');
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                //handle error
            });
        }
    },

    keyPress: function(event) {
        if (event.charCode === 13) {
            console.log('login attempt');
            this.send('login');            
        }
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work because the action is not sent from the template button to the component's action and also because from the component I can't perform the transition.

Can someone tell the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your button is part of your `home` template. Maybe the form should be moved in your `login-functions` template and be called from your `home` template by doing `{{login-functions}}`.

And for the redirection, components can't do them, I'd suggest to call an action using `this.sendAction('didLogin')` and handle the redirection in your `HomeController`.

Comment: ok; so now I get that the DOM element triggering the action must be inside of component's template; is not possible to send the action to the component if the component itself does not have a template? (if is used as a block like {{#my-component}}...(template)...{{/my-component}}?

Comment: Because the action is triggered from the `home` template, I think it is the `HomeController` that will catch it. This is why I suggest you to move your form in your component's template. By doing this, you can handle the logic in your component, and then, with the `sendAction()` method, let your controller handle the transition

Comment: And I don't know much about your architecture, but it may be a good idea to move the auth logic in the Controller as well, so you handle the form data in your component, and then, do `this.sendAction('login', username, password)` and then, in your `HomeController`, your will be to deal with your `login(username, password)` action.

Comment: well in truth I built the component just to be able to catch the keypress event for the login, since I've not been able to do it otherwise and I thought that was the right solution

Comment: unfortunally try to perform "this.sendAction('performLogin') (where 'performLogin' is defined on home Controller) has no effect; is it really possible to send an action from within a component to the wrapper template's controller?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `keyPress` functions out of the actions.

Updated --- Here is a working [demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/fc328a2dc329c537a7a7)